# The multi-part identifier could not be bound when trying to replace character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to replace the "/" character from my joined table, but I am getting a "multi-part identifier could not be bound" exception.

I am working on a relatively simple sql query. But I am getting a "multi-part identifier could not be bound" exception. I have googled the exception and found numerous posts, but I can't make it work. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT  lines.Item, vInventoryOptional2Values.Value AS Brand
UPDATE vInventoryOptional2Values.Value
SET name = REPLACE(name, ' ', '_')
FROM lines INNER JOIN inventory
ON lines.item = Inventory.item
INNER JOIN vInventoryOptional2Values
ON Inventory.Optional2 = vInventoryOptional2Values.RecordID
WHERE vInventoryOptional2Values.Value = 'dyrberg/kern'
```

THe full query looks like this (without the character replacing code):

```
SELECT  lines.Item, Inventory.ItemAlternative, Inventory.OnHandPhys, Inventory.Allocated, Inventory.CostPrice, SUM(lines.Invoiced)*-1 AS QtySoldInPeriod, (SUM(lines.AmountBase-lines.CostAmount))*-1 AS ProfitInPeriod, vInventoryOptional2Values.Value AS Brand, Inventory.Optional3 AS StockStatus
FROM lines INNER JOIN inventory
ON lines.item = Inventory.item INNER JOIN vInventoryOptional2Values
ON Inventory.Optional2 = vInventoryOptional2Values.RecordID
WHERE Lines.Date >= '2014-01-01' AND Lines.Date <= '2014-01-31'
AND lines.Invoiced < 0
AND Inventory.Status = 0
AND Inventory.Optional3 <> 3
GROUP BY Lines.Item, Inventory.Optional3, Inventory.ItemAlternative, Inventory.OnHandPhys, Inventory.CostPrice, vInventoryOptional2Values.Value, Inventory.Allocated HAVING SUM(lines.AmountBase-lines.CostAmount) < 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a `SELECT` with an `UPDATE` so you just need to exclude the first line. Also you only specify the table name in the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE vInventoryOptional2Values
SET name = REPLACE(name, ' ', '_')
FROM lines INNER JOIN inventory
ON lines.item = Inventory.item
INNER JOIN vInventoryOptional2Values
ON Inventory.Optional2 = vInventoryOptional2Values.RecordID
WHERE vInventoryOptional2Values.Value = 'dyrberg/kern'
```

Comment: Then I get the following error:Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'vInventoryOptional2Values.Value'.

Comment: Oops, missed that bit. Try now.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'name'.

Comment: Without knowing your table structure, you are going to have to help yourself here. I've given you enough to finish this yourself.

Comment: sql is not my strong side :) vInventoryOptional2Values.Value is a predefined view (if I remeber the name correctly). I think this is what is causing the problem. Just can't find the error.

Comment: The error is telling you there is no column called `name`, which column do you want to change?

Comment: I want to change the vInventoryOptional2Values.Value which is, as far as I know, a predefined view.

Comment: Then why does your statement try to update the name column? Please try to think about your problem, you don't need to be a SQL expert to fix this minor issue now.